# Schema aware xml modification

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

At Runtime I will get a XSD , XML  , Xpath expression , and a element.  I have to add this element to the xml under the element specified by xpath expression .  If Element pointed by xpath expression is sequenced then I have to add the element in its correct Position. How can I achieve that in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XQuery Update looks like what you need. It allows you to say for example

```
insert node <a>something</a> as first|last into /doc/section[2]/para[3]
```

There are a number of XQuery Update processors that can be invoked from Java, for example Saxon.